# What is the difference between get_the_author_meta() and get_user_meta()?

Tags: user-meta

I am having an issue:

- [get_the_author_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) returns the meta
- [get_user_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/) returns *false* for the same meta key

I don't know why this happens.

Regarding user metadata, when should I use one or the other?

**I tried this**:

```
get_the_author_meta('afzfp_user_status', $user->ID);
get_user_meta('afzfp_user_status', $user->ID, true);
```

**It returns**:

```
String "the meta value"
bool (false)
```

**UPDATE**:

(As pointed by [@shanebp](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/16575/shanebp)) - The parameters order is different, that is why my code is not working as expected:

```
get_the_author_meta('afzfp_user_status', $user->ID);
get_user_meta($user->ID, 'afzfp_user_status', true);
```

**The question itself still remains**: What is the difference between them and when is it recommended to use one or the other?

Comment: Can you include the code you ran for both of them? The parameters and how they're called are important

Comment: @TomJNowell Thanks for your attention, I updated my question with sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`get_the_author_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/)**: retrieves the requested data of the author of the current post.

- Parameters: ( string **$field = ''**, int|false **$user_id = false** )

**[`get_user_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/)**: retrieves user meta field for a user.

- Parameters: ( int **$user_id**, string **$key = ''**, bool **$single = false** )

---

**Example**:

John is an logged in user reading a post written by Mary.

- **`get_the_author_meta`** will return the value of a field (string) related to Mary, the author.
- **`get_user_meta`** will return the value of one (string) or more (array) meta data fields related to John.

---

**Snippets:**

**`get_the_author_meta`**

Get the email address for the author of the current post***** and store it in the `$author_email` variable for further use:

```
$author_email = get_the_author_meta( 'author_email' );
```

*****If used within The Loop, the user ID need not be specified, it defaults to current post author. A user ID must be specified if used outside The Loop.

**`get_user_meta`**

Get the last name for user id 2 and store it in the `$user_last` variable:

```
$user_last = get_user_meta( 2, 'last_name', true );
```

---

**Reference:**

**`get_the_author_meta`**: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/

**`get_user_meta`**: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter order is wrong for [get_user_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/). 
The user id should be first.

Try: `var_dump(get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'afzfp_user_status', true));`

Comment: This lack of focus should have an associated punishment. Thanks for your help! By the way I will wait before marking your answer as accepted because I still don't know when I should use one or the other. There must be a purpose in having defined two functions to retrieve user metadata. The main difference I see is one accepting the third "return single" parameter, but not sure if that's the whole reason.

Comment: The difference is that `get_user_meta` has an optional third parameter and the `$user_id` is required rather than being optional.